Adding torch.no_grad() to model evaluation stops the model completely
I am working on a pretty heavy ddpm model to denoise images. I can execute the training without any issues or OOM errors, however, when I do the inference phase, the code goes OOM.
I tried adding the "with torch.no_grad():" statement, but this blocks the code completely, without even reaching the main entry point.
What could be a fix, and what causes the error in the first place?
Below an example of the code
def denoise(model, noisy_image, timestep, device="cuda"):
# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Move the image to the appropriate device
current_image = noisy_image.to(device)

# Ensure current_image has 4 dimensions (batch_size, channels, height, width)
if current_image.dim() == 3:  # If it's a single image without batch dimension
    current_image = current_image.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

# Convert the timestep to a tensor and move it to the appropriate device
timestep_tensor = torch.tensor([timestep], dtype=torch.int, device=device)

with torch.no_grad():
    for t in range(timestep, -1, -1):
        # Convert the current timestep to a tensor for this iteration
        timestep_tensor.fill_(t)  # Update the tensor value for each step

        # Predict the noise component using the U-Net model, passing the timestep as a tensor
        noise_pred = model(current_image, timestep_tensor)

        # Compute the mean (mu_theta) for the reverse step
        mu_theta = current_image - noise_pred

        # Update the current image based on the reverse step
        current_image = mu_theta + torch.randn_like(current_image) * torch.sqrt(torch.tensor(1 - (t / timestep)))

        # Clip the intensities to the range [0, 1] as described in the paper
        current_image = torch.clamp(current_image, 0.0, 1.0)

return current_image.cpu()
# Main entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

# Load parameters from the YAML file
config = utils.load_yaml("cfg.yaml")

# Model parameters from config
in_ch = config["model"]["in_ch"]
out_ch = config["model"]["out_ch"]
resolution = config["model"]["resolution"]
num_res_blocks = config["model"]["num_res_blocks"]
ch = config["model"]["ch"]
ch_mult = tuple(config["model"]["ch_mult"])
attn_resolutions = config["model"]["attn_resolutions"]
dropout = config["model"]["dropout"]
resamp_with_conv = config["model"]["resamp_with_conv"]

# Initialize the UNet model
model = UNet(
    in_ch=in_ch,
    out_ch=out_ch,
    resolution=resolution,
    num_res_blocks=num_res_blocks,
    ch=ch,
    ch_mult=ch_mult,
    attn_resolutions=attn_resolutions,
    dropout=dropout,
    resamp_with_conv=resamp_with_conv,
)
model = model.to(device)
# Dataset directory from config
image_directory = config["dataset"]["directory"]
batch_size = config["training"]["batch_size"]

if model_train:
    # Create the dataloaders
    train_loader, val_loader, test_loader = create_dataloaders(image_directory, batch_size)
    # Train the model
    train_model(
        model,
        train_loader,  
        num_epochs=config["training"]["num_epochs"],
        learning_rate=config["training"]["learning_rate"],
        device=device,
    )

# Load the model from the saved state for inference
model = load_model("unet_denoiser_best.pth", device=device)
test_image = utils.load_image_as_tensor("img.png", device=device)
timestep = estimate_gaussian_timestep(test_image)
denoised_image = denoise(model, test_image, timestep, device=device)

utils.save_image(denoised_image, "denoised_output.png")
print("Denoised image saved as denoised_output.png")

